# jQuery ajax response not displaying when returning to current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to post some data back to the same page through ajax. In the example below the `$name` variable is not being updated in my page once the button is clicked. However, if I look at the console log of the response from ajax (using firebug) it shows the correct html, with the name inserted (i.e. `<div>Matthew</div>`) - the page just isn't being updated with this response. Any ideas for how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$name = "A name";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name = "No name!";
  }
  else{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
  }
}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){ 
       var mydata = {name: "Matthew"}; 
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: mydata,
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        });

    });
});
</script>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

<div id="name">
<?php echo $name;?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The page wont just update its self - thats the whole point of ajax, you need to use the returned data (in the success function) to update it via javascript.

Comment: Ajax doesn't work that way. Go to your `success: function`, there, you assign `data` to the `div` tag.

Comment: or just do a regular form post, sans ajax

Comment: I've just posted a simple test case here, but in my real application I need to use javascript functionality on the output of the form and then resubmit that, so ajax seemed the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `<?php echo $name;?>` does not run again when doing the ajax call. You have to replace the content of the div in the success function like this:

```
success: function(data){
            $("div").html(data);
          }
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much. That has solved my problem, although it seems that I now get the side effect of the button showing up twice! Any ideas what causes that?

Comment: @MattPitkin it is because you are loading the whole page with ajax. to load only a bit of your page you either have to put the php in a different file and call that url in your ajax arguments or use `.load( "url div" );` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks again. I realised that I could just send the data I wanted to the div element by putting `$("#name").html(mydata['name']);` in the ajax success function.

Comment: I shoulld note that when I used what's in the above comment I had added the `id="name"` to the div tag. I've edited this in the original post.