# Rerender page after Leaflet drawing with flask, ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, leaflet

Hi I'm developing an app with Flask and Leaflet maps. The map has geometry objects on it. With the help of Drawing tool user draws polygonal shapes on the map, and all the object data (i.e. 'id') that fall inside shape should be rendered in a html table.
When shape is drawn POST request is done. Although I can print out the data in traceback and see it in Devtools Network Preview tab, I still couldn't render this data in the html.

Here is my JS code that sends Post request after shape is drawn. The output gives shape vertex coordinates.

```
mymap.on('pm:create', e => {
    var map_data = e["layer"]["_latlngs"][0];
    console.log(map_data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "/",
      traditional: "true",
      data: JSON.stringify({map_data}),


      });
});
```

Then I assign a variable with this coordinates and print them out in app.py. Using different geo tools functions, I also fund stuf inside polygon:

```
shape_coord = request.get_json() //gets shape coordinates

if shape_coord:
 filter_markers = marker_within_polygon(markers, shape_coord) //function finds markers within shape
 filter_lines = lines_within_polygon(lines, shape_coord)//function finds lines within shape

 print(shape_coord)// OK
 print(filter_markers, filter_lines)//OK. prints out stuff inside polygon
```

And here is my jinja2:

```
<tbody id="table_body">

                        {% for mk in  filter_markers%}
                            <tr>
                                {% for ln in filter_lines %}
                                     <th>{{ ln }}</th>
                                     <th>{{ mk }}</th>
                                {% endfor %}
                             </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

I tried using success callback in Ajax like this, but besides required data it inserts the whole HTML-body markup inside the table:

```
mymap.on('pm:create', e => {
    var map_data = e["layer"]["_latlngs"][0];
    console.log(map_data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "/",
      traditional: "true",
      data: JSON.stringify({map_data}),
      success: function (data) {
                    $("#table_body").html(data);

      });
});
```

How can I get only my marker and line data rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The success depends on correct question)
I found answer here:
[Query ajax response not displaying when returning to current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768261/jquery-ajax-response-not-displaying-when-returning-to-current-page)